# Jupyter Notebook freezes while locating points (40k lat lon ) using Gmaps API

Tags: python, memory-management, jupyter-notebook, heap-memory

I am trying to plot around 40k lat-long points using gmaps api on jupyter notebook, however it keeps freezing .

My system confirguration as below:
[image]

Is there any way I can increase the heapsize of allocate more memory for running python and jupyter notebook and solve this issue.
I found a couple of resources but they were for linux machines, I am working on a windows machine.